# String manipulation in for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

So I just learned how to manipulate single letters in a for loop from code academy.
But let's say I made a function and wanted this function to manipulate the vowels of an user inputted word and replace the vowel with four consecutive copies of itself. How would I go about that?

Expected output:

```
>>>Exclamation("car")
caaaar
>>>Exclamation("hello")
heeeelloooo
```

So far I have:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
vowels= ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

for char in word:
    if char in vowels:
        print(____,end='') #here I am unsure of how to replace it with consecutive copies of itself

    else:
        print(char,end='')
```

Comment: Your code is, though, only _printing_ the output (a perfectly valid way to experiment). Had you considered writing a function to do the replacement? That way you can separate the printing out from the replacement logic, which will keep your code cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print statement can be:

```
print(4 * char,end='') # Or how many ever times you want to repeat it.
```

If `word` is 'car', this code:

```
>>> for char in word:
...     if char in vowels:
...         print(4 * char, end='')
...     else:
...         print(char, end='')
...
```

prints

```
caaaar
```

Note: You can include only the lower case vowels in your `vowels` list and in your `if` condition, check if `char.lower()` is in `vowels`.